# How to ignore the format error flag in the cell number format

Tags: c#, excel

My code:

```
columns = ws.get_Range("A:F", System.Type.Missing);
columns.NumberFormat = "@";
```

After I debug the program, there is green color flag beside my number cells.

Expectation:

Remove the green color flag after debugging.

What I investigated:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195953.aspx

From the MSDN itself, it only showed VBA can ignore the error in the cells. But i not really believe that c# is unable to do it.

Comment: Maybe it is different in your version of Excel, but just changing the `NumberFormat` to `"@"` is not enough to trigger the green error flag for me with Excel 2013.  I have to enter with a leading `'` or import something as `Text` (not just change the format).  Either way, your answer is below.

Answer (score 1):

There is an object on the `Application` called `ErrorCheckingOptions`.  You can change the `NumberAsText` property from `true` to `false`.

```
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = false;
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.errorcheckingoptions.numberastext(v=office.11).aspx

Note that this is a global (Application-level) option.  I haven't tested, but it is likely that this option will persist across Excel instances (that is, once you close and reopen Excel).

Comment: That link is to the Interop documentation so it should work. You will have to replace Application with whatever your Application object is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code:

```
excelRange.Cells.Value = yourValue; // Must be set before the Ignore setting
excelRange.Cells.Errors[Excel.XlErrorChecks.xlNumberAsText].Ignore = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using this, it will ignore and not show in Excel.

```
app.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = false;
```